# Merge Rows COUNTS in SQL

Tags: sql

Currently I have data in sql and need to merge the counts from rows.

My code is:

```
WHERE lower(GENDER) IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY lower(GENDER)
```

And it's out putting a table like:

```
Gender    Count
female    100 
f         101
male      102 
m         103
unknown   104
```

Is there a way to combine the counts from female and f and then similarly from male and m?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select
    case lower(gender)
        when 'f' then 'female'
        when 'm' then 'male'
        else lower(gender)
    end new_gender,
    count(*) cnt
from mytable
where gender is not null
group by case lower(gender)
        when 'f' then 'female'
        when 'm' then 'male'
        else lower(gender)
    end
```

Note that you don't need `lower()` to check if `gender` is `null`.

Some databases support positional parameters in the `group by` clause, so you can just do:

```
group by 1
```

Other databases support re-using aliases defined in the `select` clause:

```
group by new_gender
```

Comment: The note about various databases support options is likely a good addition that I didn't think to add.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you just need to somehow list how that's going to happen. This can be done using a function or a case statement.

A case statement is a fine solution for a one off query, but I'd recommend a conversion table or a function if you're going to be spreading this across multiple queries.

```sql
select
  case 
    when lower(gender) = 'f' or lower(gender) = 'female' 
      then 'female'
    when lower(gender) = 'm' or lower(gender) = 'male'
      then 'male'
  end as cleanded_gender
  , count(*) as gender_count
from
  ...
where
  gender is not null
group by
  case 
    when lower(gender) = 'f' or lower(gender) = 'female' 
      then 'female'
    when lower(gender) = 'm' or lower(gender) = 'male'
      then 'male'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your RDBM you can take the substring of Gender, only the first char,
and it will group on "f", "m", "u"... not nice, but it will work